# sed backreference regex to support spaces and tabs

Tags: regex, sed

Im am trying to write a small sed substitution one liner to add a hostname to an existing entry in an /etc/hosts file, so for example, this line

```
10.80.0.4 host.compute.internal
```

I want to inject `othername` into the line like this

```
10.80.0.4 othername host.compute.internal
```

Ive managed to put the following together using backreferences and it works fine **as long**  as the items are separated by a space

```
cat /etc/hosts |
sed  's/\(^.\+\) \(.\+compute.internal\)/\1 othername \2/g'
```

however..I need this regex to also support **Tab** separated items as well, Does anyone have any ideas how i can amend the above to support tabs **and** spaces?

any help would be greatly appreciated
thanks

Comment: do you need to support tabs and spaces in the output? Or can you convert all tabs to spaces?

Comment: Adding is one thing. How bout if the entry already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
sed -E 's/(^.+)[[:blank:]](.+compute.internal)/\1 othername \2/'
```

See [Character Classes and Bracket Expressions (sed, a stream editor)](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) for an explanation of `[[:blank:]]`.